# Api facebook v5 general statistics

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a doubt and if possible clarify,
I need to see the numbers of fans and the statistics of the fan page but any page that does not manage only that can do with the url, I consult it because I met a website that only with the url of the fanpage gives this.
How is this possible without needing permits?

Sorry for my english

Number of fans.
Post-likes

Comment: The number of likes is public; insights on specific post data however is not. If any service is giving you that kind of information for pages you are not an admin of, then they most likely obtained it in ways not allowed, like f.e. scraping.

Comment: It's the weird thing http://socialbakers.com/ I found it on that website and I really liked it

Thanks for your reply